# How to add/remove field "required" condition while saving the channel data?

Tags: expressionengine

How to add/remove field "required" condition while saving the channel data?

I want to run validation based on input received.  Using EE verstion 2.9.2

Answer (score 0):

The required attribute is managed in the same interface where you created the field.

Let's say you were trying to change the field "Body" in the fieldset named "News", you'd want to drill down on the control panel as follows:

> Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Fields > News > Body

In the resulting page toggle the radio button labeled "Is this a required field?"

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the required option from EE admin for that custom fields as described by AllInOne.

For validation you have to develop a custom extension with [entry-submission-ready](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/index.html#entry-submission-ready)   hooks.

Check this link how to develop [extension](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html) in EE.